# Why backup to ... In C # does not work

Tags: sql-server, c#-3.0, sql-server-express

I have a project that works with SqlExpress and all parts are working properly but the error in the backup with this statement:

> Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'Verjan'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
>    BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Meanwhile, the backup in a procedture
 With code

```
execute ('Use master')
Backup Database Sample to Disk = Adress
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using User Instance of the database in your project? By that I mean if you have `AttachDbFilename` in database connection string. If you do then you cannot perform a normal backup because *a)* database is not attached to your DBMS and *b)* in connection string there is a macro `|DataDirectory|` which will be resolved to actual path of .mdf file on the runtime.

There is a solution for this problem: [Backup and Restore with User Instances](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2007/03/20/backup-and-restore-with-user-instances.aspx)

Hope this helps!